# Strange CSS issue with mobile app and JQM

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I don't think this is related to JQM but maybe just the CSS.

I have a very basic mobile web page and it loads with the correct css.  There is a link on this page that links to the a similar page but with a different css reference..  but it does not apply the css until I hit refresh. I tested this with iphone browser.

anyone having similar issue or seen this?

Answer (score 0):

The way JQM works by default is that it loads each linked page, 'inside' the first page loaded, through ajax.
This is done behind the scenes.

If you want to load different content forced, the quickest way is to make the link an 'external' link using

```
<a href="location.html" rel="external">click here</a>
```

That's the way I know it will definitely not use ajax. unfortunately this disables the neat page change effects.

In the documentation it says you should use

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    // disable ajax nav
    $.mobile.ajaxLinksEnabled = false;
});
</script>
```

But this doesn't always work for me.

Remember though that Everything is reloaded, so you will have to include all of your javascript and css in the "new" page.

Another way to achieve what your asking is to load both Css files on all pages and use javascript to media tags to switch between them.

Hope this helps. I spend a long time coming up with a way to make jqm work like a classic website.